# Trying to push rails app in heroku and get a js error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, fullcalendar

I'm stacked. I've tryed to push my rails app (User+fullCalendar) and got an error:

```
 This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

My view has:

```
 <script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.0/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.0/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.0/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

Ya, problem in https and http incompatibility but if i delete script files from view calendar will not work too. What should i do ?

Comment: what happens if you change the url to ```https``` for all of them. I believe they should still work, and also satisfy heroku, at least from my experience in the past. I.e. ```<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.0/lib/moment.min.js'></script>``` etc.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald already tryed. Doesnt work anyway.

Comment: did the answer below work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use a protocol related url like this:

```
<script src='//fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.0/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='//fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.0/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="//fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.0/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src='//fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

You also need to run `rake assets:precompile` before pushing to heroku. See here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline